# Security exists or not in Modification in schnorr signature

Tags: signature, schnorr-signature

In Schnorr's digital signature protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature), 
the signature is $(s,e)$ where $s=k-xe$.
Assumption:
 $k$ and $x$ are assumed to be secret value of user.
So, ($k,x$) value is never changed except $e$. 
$s_{i}=k_{i}-x_{i}e$ for $i$ users
 
Unlike Schnorr's signature, $e$ is also kept secret so that only valid users, who knows respective k and x values, can reveal it.
Even though different $k,x$ values, $e$ is selected uniformly randomly from $ Z_{q}$ and assumed to be same for all valid users.

Does the modification secure to securely deliver different values of $e$ for every time ?

Comment: "Three can keep a secret, if two of them are dead" - Benjamin Franklin. Signatures are generally expected to be verifiable in public.

Comment: Instead of signature, just consider for simple, secure delivery of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors in your thoughts:

> k and x are assumed to be secret value of user.
>   So, (k,x) value is never changed except e.

As stated in the signing algorithm, $k$ is drawn uniformly random from the set $\mathbb{Z}_q^{\times}$. This means, it is random (and different with overwhelming probability) for every single message. Using the same $k$ might not be secure at all - I am quite sure it won't, but don't have a proof right now.

That means, in every message $k$ has a different value. This ipmplies, that $e$ has a different value (again, with overwhelming probability). And again, $s$ has a different value with overwhelming probability.

This wouldn't work, since a fixed $k$ just does not fit the algorithm's assumptions.

> Unlike Schnorr's signature, e is also kept secret so that only valid users, who knows respective k and x values, can reveal it.

This is a quite pointless in this case. If some information is known to anyone whose role isn't specified in the protocol, you have to assume that the value is publicly known.

> Even though different k,x values, e is selected uniformly randomly from Zq and assumed to be same for all valid users.

This doesn't make sense at all. Every user has his own fixed value of $k$, the protocol clearly describes how $e$ has to be calculated. If you choose $e$ independently, the whole signature does not work any more.

Adn then you write in the comments:

> Instead of signature, just consider for simple, secure delivery of e.

I thought, $e$ is the same for all users? I guess you meant $s$.

But this would mean this: Your value $s$ does not depend on the message any more. $s$ is always the same for every message.

*Summary*

This isn't a modification, it has nothing to do with the signature scheme any more. If your only modification would be a fixed $k$, chances are quite high that you already have a fatal security flaw in your setup. My guess would be, that two signatures actually reveal the secret value $x$ then.